# SQL Query using PHP PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo, percona

I'm trying to create a SQL query using PHP in which it checks to see if a row has already been submitted/set using the same date and user name. If it hasn't it inserts a new row. If it does find a match, it updates the row instead.

I can insert a new row fine, but when I use a pre-existing date and name, I receive no error in any of my logs, and the query appears to run without any problems. But when checking the database, I notice that there are no UPDATES actually set to the row. When I run the update command manually in SQL, it appears to work fine.

Having no logs/error data to go on, I was hoping to get some advice here. I'm sure there must be something I'm missing here. This is what I'm currently using:

```
require_once 'db-conn.php';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$var1 = $_POST['var1'];
$var2 = $_POST['var2'];
$var3 = $_POST['var3'];
$var4 = $_POST['var4'];

$conn = db_connect (); 
$sqlq = "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE date = '$date' AND name = '$name'"; 
$nRows = $conn->query("$sqlq")->fetchColumn();

if ($nRows==0) {
try {
  $sqli = "INSERT INTO tbl (name,email,date,var1,var2,var3,var4) VALUES (:name,:email,:date,:var1,:var2,:var3,:var4)";
   $sql = $conn->prepare("$sqli");
   $sql->execute(array(':name' => $name, ':email' => $email, ':date' => $date, ':var1' => $var1, ':var2' => $var2, ':var3' => $var3 ':var4' => $var4));
 } catch(PDOException $e) {
   die ('SQL Error');
   }
 }
else {
 try {
  $sqli = "UPDATE tbl SET email='$email', notes='$notes', var1='$var1', var2='$var2', var3='$var3' WHERE date='$date' AND name='$name'";
  $sql = $conn->prepare("$sqli");
  $sql->execute(array($name, $email, $date, $var1, $var2, $var3, $var4));
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  die ('SQL Error');
}
```

}

Comment: Be careful in your SELECT statement; you're feeding two unsanitized variables directly in. I would also prepare that statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have the bound variables correct:

```
$sqli = "UPDATE tbl SET email=:email, notes=:notes, var1=:var1, var2=:var2, var3=:var3 WHERE date=:date AND name=:name";
$sql = $conn->prepare("$sqli");
$sql->execute(array(':name' => $name, ':email' => $email, ':date' => $date, ':var1' => $var1, ':var2' => $var2, ':var3' => $var3, ':notes'=>$notes));
```

You did it correct in the Insert statement but not in the update.

Not sure where you are getting `$notes` from though.

Plus not sure if it is intentional or not but you are not updating var4 in the update query.

Comment: I forgot to mask $notes with $var# :). I tend to mask my unique var names when posting on here, heh. I will try the changes mentioned where the variables get bounded for my UPDATE query. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my query to include binding variables, but PDOException reports the following when running the UPDATE query: 
    exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number' in temp.html Stack trace: #0 temp.html(34): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 temp-php.php(18): include('/xxx/xxx/incl...') #2 {main}

Comment: That means the number of `:variables` in the `$sqli` don't match the number of variables sent in the array on `execute()` make sure they match up.

Comment: I've bound the variables, but one of the big problems I had was that the WHERE date=:date and name=:name didn't work, but did work when using the unsanitized variables. I'll be marking your answer as correct, but before doing so, any words of advice on why this would be? My SQL query did not appear to replace :name and :date with the sanitized variable.

Comment: looks like the issue was the two variables :date and :name repeating itself in one query. i was able to remove those from the UPDATE query and it works great. the user won't be able to update the date or name, but there isn't much of a need for changing those variables in particular. many thanks for the words of advice.